# Japanese equivalent of "Mmmm" as in "Mmmm I like that!" or "Mmmm, delicious"

Tags: phrase-requests, interjections

What's the Japanese equivalent of "Mmmm" as in "Mmmm I like that!" or "Mmmm, delicious"?

"Mmmm" used as a tone of appreciation or approbation, NOT of deliberation as in "Mmmm, let me think about that"

Comment: What are you even talking about? How is your question censored? I helped make your question clearer and better formatted. Please refer to the [Help Center](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help) for our question and answer policies.

Comment: it was perfectly clear.   if you don't understand, you probably never will....    cheers

Answer (score 5):

You can say:

- **うーん**、素晴らしい！ (neutral)
- **んー**、素晴らしい！ (casual)
- **うーむ**、素晴らしい！ (pompous)
- **ふーむ**、素晴らしい！ (pompous)

Note that the actual pronunciations of these う/ふ/む may be different from what you already know. These interjections are often pronounced just like English "mmm" or "hmmm". See: [IPA for ふーん/んふふ (pronounced with your mouth closed)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/57847/5010) and [Difference between うーん and ううん](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/8263/5010)

Comment: your top two suggestions are what I was thinking...   never come across the other two....   not sure really about the parenthesized observations:  neutral "wonderful!'?  especially.  but food for thought, thank you.

Comment: @jiji_Xx I wanted to say ふーむ sounds like an intelligent old man ([like this](https://stock.adobe.com/jp/images/elderly-man/78226698)). うーん does not have such a tone.